# Sql to return false if all records not found based on dates and value in field

Tags: sql-server

Sorry if that wasn't too clear but it is hard to sum up.

Table `Holiday` which has one field named `hDate`
   Table `TimeSheet` which has `tsDate,Code`

Sample Data

```
   Holiday
   7/4/2012
   12/24/2012
   12/25/2012
   12/26/2012
```

Sample Data

```
   TimeSheet
   12/27/2012,W
   12/24/2012,H
   12/25/2012,W
```

I need to verify based on a date range that every record in the Holiday table that is between the date range exists in the Timesheet table and that they have an H value entered for Code

So if the date range passed in was 12/24-12/30 then the results should be empty since no data exists in timesheet for 12/26 and 12/25 has a code W in it. So basically I need an exists query to do this

Comment: Can you also please provide an example the _would_ return results?  Based upon your question and sample data, I would think that 12/26 needs to be flagged as missing from TimeSheet and that 12/25 needs an H.

Comment: correct. If the date is missing from the timesheet or included and doesn't have an H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following SQL. It counts the number of code <> 'H' and tsDate = null from the left outer join. If the count > 0, then return false.

```
DECLARE @Holiday TABLE
(
    hDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @TimeSheet TABLE
(
    tsDate DATETIME, 
    Code NCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Holiday (hDate)
VALUES ('2012-07-04'), ('2012-12-24'), ('2012-12-25'), ('2012-12-26')

INSERT INTO @TimeSheet (tsDate, Code)
VALUES ('2012-12-27', 'W'), ('2012-12-24', 'H'), ('2012-12-25', 'W')

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2012-12-24'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2012-12-30'

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(1) = 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS 'BooleanResult'
FROM
    (
        SELECT hDate 
        FROM @Holiday 
        WHERE hDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    ) H 
    LEFT JOIN @TimeSheet TS
    ON TS.tsDate = H.hDate
WHERE 
    TS.Code != 'H' OR TS.tsDate IS NULL and 'H' not in (select doecode from timesheet 
where timesheet.tsdate = TS.tsDate
```

Comment: Almost perfect. I should have mentioned this before but you can have more then 1 entry per day so if someone has for 12/25 2 entries 1 with an H and another with a W it should return true but it is returning false